# python regex matching between multiple lines and every other match

Tags: python, regex

So I've been playing around with this for a few days and here is what I am looking for and the regex I have now. I have a file in this  format (there are some other fields but I have omitted those:

I just want to match the bold text

```
ADDR 1 - XXXXXX   ADDR 1 - **XXXXXX**

ADDR 2 - XXXXXX   ADDR 2 - XXXXXX

ADDR 1 - XXXXXX   ADDR 1 - **XXXXXX**

ADDR 2 - XXXXXX   ADDR 2 - XXXXXX
```

The regex I have  written only matches the first ADDR 1 - XXXXX, but I need to match all instances of the bolded XXXXX.

```
re.findall(r'ADDR 1- .*? ADDR 1-(.*?)(?=ADDR 2-)', lines, re.DOTALL)
```

Any suggestions? I feel like I might be  missing something simple, but not sure.

Comment: Are these lines separate strings? Or is it single multiline text? Try `re.findall(r'ADDR 2 .*? ADDR 2 - (.*)', s)` without any flags. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR7eU3/1).

Comment: Try using `re.M` (`re.MULTILINE`) ...

Comment: If you know that it will always be the second instance of ADDR1, can't you capture all of them in a list and then slice out the second instances? e.g. `second_instances = list_of_all_addr1[1::2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code:**

```
import re

str= """
ADDR 1 - XXXXXX ADDR 1 - ABCDEF

ADDR 2 - XXXXXX ADDR 2 - XXXXXX

ADDR 1 - XXXXXX ADDR 1 - UVWXYZ

ADDR 2 - XXXXXX ADDR 2 - XXXXXX
"""

m = re.findall(r".*ADDR\s+1\s+-\s+(.*)",str)
print m
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
['ABCDEF', 'UVWXYZ']

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

**How it works:**

```
.*ADDR\s+1\s+-\s+(.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/90HlB1jEj2mJ_4V_)

Lets take a line - **ADDR 1 - XXXXXX ADDR 1 - ABCDEF**

- `.*ADDR` will match *ADDR 1 - XXXXXX ADDR*. Since `.*` match anything and by nature regex are greedy, so to stop I have add `ADDR` after `.*`
- `\s+1\s+-\s+(.*)` will match rest  *1 - ABCDEF*. `\s+1\s+-\s+` is required since we need to match *ADDR 1* and not *ADDR 2*. `(.*)` will match *ABCDEF* and store it.

Comment: Thank you it works - need to tweak it a bit. Could you explain a bit? I will accept your answer as soon as I fix it!

Comment: I just  modified it it because I needed  it to stop before another place where it said address 1. .*ADDR\s+1-\s+(.*)\s+ADDR 2- (let me know if this  should be fixed). For  some  reason I also needed Global too.

Comment: The re.MULTILINE flag is redundant here, you may remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If wanting to capture every other instance of something then splitting or slicing the string is going to be **much faster** than using regex — the following demonstrates a very *basic* example:

***split()*** method:

```
>>> [i.split('ADDR 1 - ')[-1] for i in s.split('\n')[::2]]
>>> ['AXXXXZ', 'AXXXXY']
>>> ''' 18.3057999611 seconds - 10000000 iterations '''
```

***findall()*** method:

```
>>> re.findall(".*ADDR\s+1\s+-\s+(.*)", s)
>>> ['AXXXXZ', 'AXXXXY']
>>> ''' 77.5003650188 seconds - 10000000 iterations '''
```

In situations where you know regex isn't absolutely necessary consider using an alternative. Also the regex shown in the accepted answer could be optimized to cut the time nearly in half (eg. `re.findall("ADDR 1 .+ - (.+)", s`) - `37.0185003658 seconds - 10000000 iterations`.